# How do I tell Select2 to search from data-attr in addition to the option text (search from multiple attributes in select2 tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, jquery-select2

I have a select2 in my rails app for customer names, now the search feature works well with customer names as option's text are set to customer name, now I want the select2 to perform the search for customer's contact_no too.
And I am setting customer's contact_no in data-attr in each option tag.
So, how the searching can be performed from the data-attr in addition with the option text.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
Here is the HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="1" data-contact-no="9898989898">Zamir</option>
    <option value="2" data-contact-no="6767676767">Manihar</option>
    <option value="2" data-contact-no="666666">Zimmie</option>
</select>
```

and JavaScript

```
$("select").select2();
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, just initialize the select2 as:

```
function matchCustom(params, data) {
// If there are no search terms, return all of the data
if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
  return data;
}

// Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
  return null;
}

// `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
// `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1 || data.element.getAttribute('data-contact-no').indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
  var matchedData = $.extend({}, data, true);

  // You can return matched objects from here
  return matchedData;
}

// Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
return null;
}

$("select").select2({
  matcher: matchCustom
});
```

Any other solution would be appreciated.
Thank You